# Prestashop: Out of Memory (allocated ...) in ../../../classes/Configuration.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, memory, prestashop, http-status-code-500

Prestashop suddenly gives an **http 500 error**. I turned on error log and got this:

> "Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 709623808) (tried to allocate
>   130968 bytes) in
>   /var/www/vhosts/44/252639/webspace/httpdocs/shop.mywebsite.com/classes/Configuration.php
>   on line 206".

I double checked the `Configuration.php` on line 206 and it's just a standard prestashop file, nothing weird in it. After all it's an "Out of memory" error so maybe I should increase memory.

`phpinfo()` shows `memory_limit 1024M`, which is already pretty much, but maybe I should try 2048M. I tried to create a new custom php.ini but that did not work, because *(according to phpinfo)* the loaded ini file is searched in this directory: `/opt/alt/php56/etc`.

My hosting provider does not allow me to edit it, it's read only.

What could I do to solve the problem ?

I did not make a backup yet.

Comment: Activate your Prestashop cache, this should alleviate your memory issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not do this, so I just turned on Smarty Cache. However, it did not work... I then disabled all non-prestashop modules, but it didn't work either. Do you maybe have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It had nothing to do with not having enough memory or whatever. Someone created a product and that caused errors, I don't know what exactly but for everyone in the future:

- Create a backup
- Turn off third party modules
- Delete all products
- Delete cache
  etc etc. **until your webpage loads correctly again -> 
  after that, restore your backup and just delete what caused the error.**

Hope it will work.