# Error in Prestashop Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file

Tags: prestashop

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop/cache/smarty/compile\06\99\53\0699537d98e8ffcfde91527d2e58a586c1a64d88.file.header.tpl.php' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(201): Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', '<?php /* Smarty...', Object(Smarty)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(155): Smarty_Internal_Template->compileTemplateSource() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\AdminController.php(1521): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('header.tpl') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\Controller.php(198): AdminControllerCore->display() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\Dispatcher.php(373): ControllerCore->run() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\backoffice\ind in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 73
```

Dont know how to fix this Please help me, folder permission set to 777  but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

if using cpanel and prestashop version 1.6 - 1.7:

1. go to folder cache -> smarty -> compile
2. delete all. nb: not included index.php

go to admin panel prestashop 1.6 - 1.7: 
 1. to advance parameter -> performance 
 2. clear cache (button in top left)

another tips.
 1. backup and generate .htaccess
 2. cek out of memory server --> [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145262/prestashop-out-of-memory-allocated-in-classes-configuration-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
 3. if using cpanel. go to cpanel -> select PHP version (if using 1.6 version try 5.4, if using 1.7 version try php 7 up)

Comment: i have done what you told, but its not working again the same error came, im using in local